# WIX: How to reference a Property within an XmlConfig element?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to have my installer be able to accept user input that will be written to node values in a configuration file.

Something like this:

```
<xmlConfig Id="myConfigElement> File="{INSTALLFOLDER]\config...myConfigFile.xml" Action ="create" On="install" Node="value"
Name="name" Value="[propertyContainingUsersInput]"
ElementPath="//pathToNode...[\[]@Name = 'oldName'[\]]" Sequence = "1"/>
```

I've tried various combinations of escape sequences around "propertyContainingUsersInput" but can't get anything to work.
Any advice is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use setproperty element like:

```
<SetProperty Id="COMPUTERNAME" Value="[%COMPUTERNAME]" Before="CostFinalize" Sequence="ui" />
```

Only that way your property will be set according UI inputs.